# Brake pedal traveling further than before

Tags: brakes, mazda, mazda-3

After replacing front brake pads on my 2010 Mazda 3,
the brake pedal travels further than before, that is they are not as touchy.

What could cause this?

Comment: This could just be the break-in period.

Answer (score 5):

If the brake discs (rotors) were scored and weren't replaced or resurfaced then you will loose some of the contact between the brake pads and the discs until the pads wear to match the disc (the break in period that @Paulster2 mentions).

Another possibility is different pad material. Or it is possible that some air was introduced into the system (unlikely if just the pads were replaced).

Comment: Yes, the rotor on drivers side was scored and didn't have time replace so went ahead just went ahead with the pads.